# getting 404 errors Welcome class - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded CodeIgniter v3.

But I'm getting 404 error :

http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/Welcome.php

Where is my wrong ?

**routes.php :**

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;


$route['default_controller'] = 'index';
$route['pages/(:any)']       = "page/get/$1";

$controllers = array('bank','baseController','contact','cron','faq','inbox','index','livescore',
    'msg','news','odds','page','profile','poll','rss','setting','traction','user' ,'shop' , 'product' , 'ad'  , 'comment','login','Welcome');

foreach($controllers as $controller) {
    $route[$controller] = $controller . "/index";
    $route[$controller . "/(:any)"] = $controller . "/$1";
}
```

**config.php :**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

my `.htaccess` :

Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>



RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.vitrinsaz1.ir
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: show your ht-access file

Comment: your folder structure in public_html

Comment: I have not any `htaccess ` file in `public_html` dir .

Comment: Their are three folder like this http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/ any reason for this type of structure

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/codeigniter-installation-beginner-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Add **Mobile** to array **$controllers**

```
$controllers = array('bank','baseController','contact','cron','faq','inbox','index','livescore',
'msg','news','odds','page','profile','poll','rss','setting','traction','user' ,'shop' , 'product' , 'ad'  , 'comment','login','Welcome','Mobile');
```

Comment: Try again. I edit my answer. `$config['index_page'] = '' ` maintain as well.

Comment: Maybe you can try your link also to be like this:
`http://www.vitrinsaz1.ir/index.php/Mobile/Vitrinsaz/Pannel/`

Comment: your `.htaccess` should be the same location as `index.php` located.